aliasing String arguments and parameters for methods in Java
I know that when you pass an object in as an argument to a method, the formal parameter object in that method becomes an alias of the argument/actual parameter. Unless that's actaully wrong, I don't understand why this isn't the case for String objects.
Here's the code I used to test this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "word";
    
    method(word);
    
    System.out.println(word); // Prints "word"
}
    
public static void method(String str) {
    str = str.substring(0, 1);
}

I also tried this same code with String word = new String("word");, which had the same result.
TL;DR: Why don't String parmeters become aliases of the argument when methods are called? Do Strings only alias under certain conditions?

That is actually wrong. The argument is evaluated as an expression, and the value of the expression (which may be a primitive or a reference) is used as the initial value of the formal parameter. There's no aliasing.

It is not an alias. str is a copy of the reference that word contains. You assign a new value to str but that doesn't change word.

(Note that you never "pass an object in as an argument" - no expression results in an object, only a primitive or a reference.)

f1sh is correct. This is because java is pass-by-value

and this is not specific to String. valid for all kind of parameters, even primitives: void method (int i) { i = i + 1; } called as int x = 0; method(x); System.out.println(x); will print 0 and not 1 (not to be confused with changing the content/state of an object. like from an array for example)
